# Include a file without change its relative path

Tags: php

i have a php script and i want to integrated with themes. So i created a themes folder and inside this i have some themes, everyone into its folder, something like this

```
css-folder
js-folder
...
themes-folder
    ----------theme1-folder
                   css-folder
                    ...
                    --------index.php 
    ----------theme2-folder
                    css-folder 
                    ... 
                    --------index.php  
...
index.php
```

Lets say i have choose the theme1 for my script, 
how can i include the index.php from the theme1 folder 
into the root index.php without change its relative paths?

If i use this

```
include "theme1-folder/index.php";
```

into the root index.php 
then all the links into the themes index.php like css and js show into the roots folders

Sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 1):

save the theme path to a variable

```
$current_them = "theme1-folder";
include "$current_theme/index.php";
```

Comment: i am afraid that you didn't understand the question, my problem is not how to choose the theme, but every theme i will choose to include then its link will be refer according to its new location. You have to read first before you answer and rate

Comment: You should include the theme path in your css link too, like this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $current_theme?>/css_folder/style.css">`. And I didn't vote you down.

Comment: Yes, i know this, but i have to do it to every link and every src. And what about url images in css? they will point to the original folder

Comment: You should put your code in the `html head` to an isolated file like a `head.php`, then you can change only once. image url in your css is relative to your css file, so you don't have to concern it.

Comment: Yes css urls working normaly but <img src="relative-url"/> not working, needs full path.

Comment: Yes, you have to add it one by one. `PHP` cannot help more.

Comment: If you think I really provided some help, please vote my answer up or accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better solution. But i used to do like this:

```
 //Define the document root path
 define("ROOT_PATH","/What/ever/My/DocumentRoot/is/");

 //Then from everywhere i can include files, writing the path from ROOT
 include(ROOT_PATH . "themes-folder/theme1-folder/index.php");
```

Simple and easy.

**Edit since the question has changed:**

What you are experiencing isn't a php problem, you have problems with your relative paths inside your html.

You can solve this by adding

```
<base href="http://www.w3schools.com/images/">
```

in your header. This tells the browser that all relative paths should originate from http://www.w3schools.com/images/.

Comment: i am afraid that you didn't understand the question, my problem is not how to choose the theme, but every theme i will choose to include then its link will be refer according to its new location. You have to read first before you answer and rate

Comment: do you mean that your anchor tags inside index.php gets wierd?